# Can a punctuation mark at the end of a quote be changed to a period to end a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, quotations, semicolons, quotation-marks, periods

For example, say I wanted to quote the following line of poetry: "To cloke your weariness;"

The line ends in a semicolon. However, what would I do if I wanted to quote it at the end of a sentence? Which one would be correct?

a) "To cloke your weariness;".

b) "To cloke your weariness;."

c) "To cloke your weariness."